# Install Sqitch on Strawberry Perl Failed

Tags: windows, installation, strawberry-perl, sqitch

I am trying to install Sqitch on Strawberry Perl (Windows 10) by following the steps from [here](https://sqitch.org/download/windows/) but failed:

```
Running Build for D/DW/DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.1.0.tar.gz
Building App-Sqitch
  DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.1.0.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build -- OK
Running Build test for DWHEELER/App-Sqitch-v1.1.0.tar.gz
t/add.t ............. ok
t/base.t ............ 88/189 '--nosuchscript.ply--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
t/base.t ............ ok
t/blank.t ........... ok
t/bundle.t .......... ok
t/change.t .......... ok
t/changelist.t ...... ok
t/check.t ........... ok
t/checkout.t ........ ok
t/command.t ......... ok
t/config.t .......... ok
t/configuration.t ... ok
t/conn_cmd_role.t ... ok
t/cx_cmd_role.t ..... ok
t/datetime.t ........ 1/33 Got 0 parameters but expected at least 1 for _check_set_locale_params
```

I am not sure why I got these 2 problems:

1. '--nosuchscript.ply--' is not recognized as an internal or external command
2. Got 0 parameters but expected at least 1 for _check_set_locale_params

What steps do I need to do to fix them? Thank you.

Comment: 1. `'--nosuchscript.ply--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` is a warning that the test intentionally creates. It's supposed to capture it so that you never see it, but for some reason on Windows it doesn't. It's harmless, as that test passes.

Comment: 2. `Got 0 parameters but expected at least 1 for _check_set_locale_params` is [a message from the Perl DateTime module](https://github.com/houseabsolute/DateTime.pm/blob/582fe366fe111914e43eba8beb2e87e74b312fea/lib/DateTime.pm#L2116-L2122). I don't know why it's happening; was there any other output after that?

Comment: I also had issues installing sqitch, a compilation failure. Didn't bother to find out how to fix it, it should just work out of the box. I resorted to the docker version of sqitch, it's easy to install docker on Windows and get sqitch going on it.